# How to animate input box and btn search

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have the following code and animation is not working as expected.
On focusout inputbox animates nice but btn_search returns to its place without animation.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::text('pretraga',null,['id'=>'pretraga','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'pretraga...'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>', ['id'=>'btn_search', 'class'=>'btn btn-default'])!!}
</div>

$("#pretraga").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate({width: '250px'}, "slow");
});
$("#pretraga").focusout(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate({width: '100%'}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't see the code for animating the `btn_search`? You seem to be only animating `#pretraga` element on both `click` as well as on `focusout`.

Comment: Yes, but when it is animated input moves and btn_search to right.

Comment: and when the focus is lost animates only input,  and btn returns to its place without animation and returns before the complete animation.

Comment: can you share a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem please? I am failing to understand your expectation and what actually is happening here.

Comment: works nicely on  jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5smz6gv1/ , I just changed the width from {width: '100%'} to {width: '150px'},

Comment: so its all good now eh?

Comment: yes that thanks to the engagement